# Trouble installing gnome-activity-journal

Tags: zeitgeist

The following happens after attempting to run gnome-activity-journal (from a purge then reinstall)

```
 $ gnome-activity-journal &
    [1] 5252
    $ /usr/share/themes/Orta/gtk-2.0/Styles/Panel/panel-dark-default.rc:20: Unable to locate image file in pixmap_path: "/Panel/panel-dark.png"
    ** Message: pygobject_register_sinkfunc is deprecated (GstObject)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/bin/gnome-activity-journal", line 94, in <module>
        from src.main import PortalWindow
      File "/usr/share/gnome-activity-journal/src/main.py", line 30, in <module>
        from activity_widgets import MultiViewContainer, TimelineViewContainer, ThumbViewContainer
      File "/usr/share/gnome-activity-journal/src/activity_widgets.py", line 35, in <module>
        from store import ContentStruct, CLIENT
      File "/usr/share/gnome-activity-journal/src/store.py", line 504, in <module>
        STORE = Store()
      File "/usr/share/gnome-activity-journal/src/store.py", line 367, in __init__
        days_population = ZeitgeistDBusInterface().get_extension("Log", "journal/activity").GetHistogramData()
      File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/zeitgeist/client.py", line 83, in __getattr__
        raise TypeError("Unknown method name: %s" % name)
    TypeError: Unknown method name: GetHistogramData
```

I'm going to assume that the panel image missing error is irrelevant (I deleted it so that I can have a transparent panel).  Anyway, I'm curious if there is a way I can resolve these errors so I can actually run gnome-activity-journal.

Edit: this is from installing gnome-activity-journal-

```
Unpacking gnome-activity-journal (from .../gnome-activity-journal_0.5.0.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.en_US.utf8.cache...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
gtk-update-icon-cache: The generated cache was invalid.
WARNING: icon cache generation failed
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for gconf2 ...
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Setting up gnome-activity-journal (0.5.0.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for python-support ...
```

Comment: What does the theme has to do with the GAJ?

Comment: There's an error at the beginning related to the theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that there's already a bug reported for this:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-activity-journal/+bug/638217

You can try to run `zeitgeist-daemon --replace`

Comment: Edited to show the installation output.. doesn't appear that there are any relevant errors.

Answer (score 3):

[Here's an answer from a GAJ developer](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-activity-journal/+bug/638217):

> Zeitgeist was running (because you had
>   used GNOME Activity Journal, Sezen,
>   Unity, an application with Zeitgeist
>   integration or whatever) at the point
>   you installed the GNOME Activity
>   Journal update.
>
> The latest GNOME Activity Journal
>   includes (and requires) an extension
>   for Zeitgeist which provides the
>   GetHistogramData method. However,
>   since Zeitgeist was already running
>   (and extensions are only loaded when
>   Zeitgeist starts) it wasn't being used
>   yet when you tried to launch the
>   Activity Journal.
>
> After **restarting Zeitgeist** (manually /
>   closing your session / rebooting the
>   computer / whatever) the extension
>   gets picked up the next time Zeitgeist
>   starts and so this problem shouldn't
>   be happening again.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have a file called "gnome_activity_journal.py" in your .local/share/zeitgeist/extensions directory. 
if not then download from http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gnome-zeitgeist/gnome-activity-journal/trunk/download/head%3A/gnome_activity_journ-20100726164417-6eyauzy3rk1f1i05-2/gnome_activity_journal.py
place this file in the directory mentioned above then restart zeitgeist by doing "zeitgeist-daemon --replace"